# Dynamic loading of modules and components at runtime in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been looking to develop a method for loading modules and/or components into an AOT-compiled Angular 4 application and been stymied by a variety of solutions that never quite seem to get me where I want to be.

My requirements are as such:

- My main application is AOT compiled, and has no knowledge of what it is loading until runtime, so I cannot specifically identify my dynamic module as an entry component at compile time (which is explicitly necessary for the 'dynamic' component loading example presented on Angular.io)
- I'd ideally love to be able to pull the code from a back end database via a GET request, but I can survive it simply living in a folder alongside the compiled site.
- I'm using Webpack to compile my main application, breaking it into chunks - and so a lot of the SystemJS based solutions seem like dead ends - based on my current research, I could be wrong about this.
- I don't need to know or have access to any components of my main application directly - in essence, I'd be loading one angular app into another, with the dynamically loaded module only perhaps having a few tightly controlled explicit interface points with the parent application.

I've explored using tools like SystemJsNgModuleLoader - which seems to require that I have the Angular compiler present, which I'm happy to do if AOT somehow allowed me to include it even if I'm not using it elsewhere. I've also looked into directly compiling my dynamic module using ngc and loading the resulting ngfactory and compiled component/module, but I'm not clear if this is at all possible or if so - what tools Angular makes available to do so. I have also seen references to ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS - but can't clearly dig up what the limitations of this are, as first analysis indicates its not quite what I'm looking for either.

I had assumed I might be able to define a common interface and then simply make a get request to bring my dynamic component into my application - but Angular seems painfully allergic to anything I try to do short of stepping outside of it alltogether and trying to attach non-angular code to the DOM directly.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Does Angular 2+ simply despise this kind of on the fly modification of its internal application architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an article that describes exactly what you are trying to do. In short you need to take over the bootstrap lifecycle.

The magic is in this snippet here.
`import {AComponentNgFactory, BComponentNgFactory} from './components.ngfactory.ts';
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AComponent, BComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap(app) {
    fetch('url/to/fetch/component/name')
      .then((name)=>{ this.bootstrapRootComponent(app, name)});
  }
  bootstrapRootComponent(app, name) {
    const options = {
      'a-comp': AComponentNgFactory,
      'b-comp': BComponentNgFactory
    };`

https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-manually-bootstrap-an-angular-application-9a36ccf86429

Comment: Granted this is an old thread but is this still true today with NG11+?